# How to check if id greater than a set of values in sql

Tags: sql

How do I check if a particular id is greater than a(any of) set of values directly..

I thought this would work...but it isn't.. Let table be some table with a column id

```
select id from table where id > any (2,3,4)
```

I get the following error

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '2,3,4)'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT id FROM table WHERE id > GREATEST(2,3,4)
```

UPD: Of course, LEAST, not GREATEST, sorry (thanks @brad).

Comment: Needs > LEAST, not greatest

Comment: This is what I was searching for... Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

```
select id from table where id > 2
```

You can just filter out the minimum value in your group and test against that.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a subquery

```
SELECT id
FROM   table
WHERE  id > ANY (select MIN(ID) from QueryGeneratingListOfIDs)
```